# How do we find the definition of a variable using VSCode's Extensions API?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

Is there a way to find the definition of a variable using VSCode's Extensions API for a TSX/TS project if the variable is defined in another file?

For example:

```js
// file_1.tsx

const randomConstantVariable = "Hello World"
```

```js
// file_2.tsx

import { randomConstantVariable } from "./someFile.ts"

console.log(randomConstantVariable)
```

I would like to access the definition of the `randomConstantVariable` in my Hover Provider when I'm working on `file_2.tsx`, but I'm not sure if there's an built-in way to do it using VSCode's Extensions API.

I tried using `vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.workspaceSymbolProvider", "randomConstantVariable")` but it can't seem to find `file_1.tsx`.

It seems like it's possible, since when I hover over a variable, VSCode is able to pick up the definition to display on the pop-up. I just wonder if this feature is somewhere in their API that I'm not seeing or if it's just built into VSCode but not exposed to the API.